# ¿Por qué el selector obtiene diferentes resultados usando jQuery y Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo una duda la cual quisiera resolver, en el sitio de Google News (en mi caso https://news.google.com.ar/ ) quiero obtener los títulos principales, para lo cual sería:

```
var foo = $('h2')// obtengo solo la primera coincidencia
```

Pero si utilizo JavaScript plano:

```
var toor = document.getElementsByTagName("h2"); // aquí obtengo todas las coincidencias.
```

¿Por qué pasa esto y cómo debo hacer para obtener todas las coincidencias con jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer es una version modificada de jquery, ya que si tambien usas un selector por clase:

```
$(".esc-lead-article-title")
```

Solo arroja la primera coincidencia también.

Utilize la siguiente [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquerify/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc) de chrome para injectar jQuery en la pagina, y si vuelves a correr `$('h2')` ahora si funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 2):

En la siguiente prueba, muy simple, podras observar que el selector de jquery aplica correctamente.

```js
$(function(){

   var h2 = $("h2");
   
   var seleccion= [];
   $.each(h2,function(){
      seleccion.push($(this).html());
   });
   
   $("#titulos").html(seleccion.join());
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>titulo1</h2>
    <h2>titulo2</h2>
    <h2>titulo3</h2>
    <div id="titulos"></div>
<body>
```

Aunque debo mencionar que al usar la consola de Chrome me desoriento ya que se observa el mismo efecto que mencionas. Pero luego usando jquery desde código el selector aplico de forma correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

```js
//-----------------------  PureJS

  var titulos = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
  var titulos_obtenidos = [];

  for (e = 0; e < titulos.length; e++) {
    var titulo = titulos[e].innerText
    titulos_obtenidos.push(titulo);
  }

  console.log('--------------------------PureJS');
  console.log(titulos_obtenidos)


//------------------------ jQuery

$(document).ready(function() {
  var titulos = $('h2');
  var titulos_obtenidos = [];

  for (e = 0; e < titulos.length; e++) {
    var titulo = titulos.eq(e).text()
    titulos_obtenidos.push(titulo);
  }

  console.log('--------------------------jQuery');
  console.log(titulos_obtenidos);


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Psicólogo recomienda cambiar de pareja cada cinco años</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Hallan una megatierra que quiebra las reglas astronómicas</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">¡Furor por Ricky Martin! El cantante llegó a Villa María y las fans fueron por él</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Andrea Rincón, ¿de novia con una música?</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Un agente de Infantería chocó a un auto estacionado y atropelló a una turista en Mar del Plata</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Todos con los Stones: el día en que los elencos de La Leona y Los ricos no piden permiso posaron abrazados</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Messi fue intervenido con éxito y ya está en su casa</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Los puntajes del estreno goleador de River ante Quilmes</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Atlético Mineiro rechazó una oferta millonaria por Pratto</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Emanuel Más confía en el trabajo de Guede: "Ya se verán los resultados"</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Confirman el primer caso de zika en la provincia de Buenos Aires</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Las lluvias podrían potenciar la epidemia del dengue</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Posible caso de dengue hemorrágico en la ciudad</h2> 
<h2 class="esc-lead-article-title-wrapper">Un estudio confirma los beneficios de andar en bici</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como [ya han dicho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3839/377) no es jQuery. Sin embargo no es una version modificada de jQuery.

En su lugar es una función que define el navegador para facilitar la depuración. Podemos encontrar la función de ayuda `$` defina en [Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#selector), donde es equivalente a [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), asi como [en FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands), [en Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide/console/command-line#css-selector-string) e Internet Explorer... no encuentro la documentación referente a `$` en Internet Explorer, pero tengo evidencia que existe en Internet Explorer 11:

[image: $ en Internet Explorar]

Como se ve en la imagen, puedes comprobar que estas son funciones nativas navegando a `about:blank`, abriendo la consola y escribiendo '$'.

Estas funciones `$` (entre otras) solo están disponibles en la consola de las herramientas de desarrollo, y por tanto no deben usarse en producción. Como dije antes, su propósito es facilitar la depuración. Además debe anotarse que si alguna librería (por ejemplo jQuery) define `window.$` entonces la consola utilizará el `$` que define la librería en lugar de la función nativa del navegador.

Para demostrar que no funcionan en producción, el siguiente código:

```js
console.log($('*'));
```

Addenum: En caso que no quede claro que demuestra este código, el punto es que `$` está disponible por defecto en la consola de las herramientas de desarrollador, pero no está disponible en producción a menos que haya sido definido (por ejemplo agregando jQuery a la página). Como dije antes puedes ir a `about:blank`, abrir la consola de las herramientas de desarrollador y escribir `$('*')` y vas a encontrar que funciona a pesar que `about:blank` no tenga código, ni ninguna librería que defina `$`.

Answer (score -4):

Obviamente no se puede comparar los resultados por que la ejecución no hace lo mismo. Observa; Si queremos obtener la primera coincidencia así como lo hace jQuery, Zepto u otras herramientas selectoras, tenemos que hacer lo siguiente:

```
//Partiendo de un código HTML
<div id="container"><p>
    inside paragraph
    <span>inside span</span>
    inside paragraph
    <span>inside span</span>
</p></div>
```

Seleccionamos el primer elemento `span`:

```
<script> var first_span = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]; </script>
```

Puedes obtener mejores resultados para complejos selecciones con vanilla JS, revisa [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: *Obviamente no se puede comparar los resultados por que la ejecución no hace lo mismo* sucede que cuando ejecutas `$('<tagName>')` en jQuery donde `<tagName>` es el nombre de un tag HTML ejecuta **lo mismo** que `document.getElementsByTag`. La pregunta que hace el autor es **¿por qué sucede esto?**

Comment: `$('<tagName>')` no es lo mismo que `document.getElementsByTagName('<tagName>')`. **Sucede esto porque** las instrucciones de código que implementa jQuery para el selector por nombre, se basa en retornar un objeto de la primera coincidencia con la forma: `getElementsByTagName('<tagName>')[0]`, mientras que los navegadores; a través de su función getElementsByTagName() retorna un arreglo con todas las coincidencias.

Comment: [Este fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdnu7sna/) demuestra que cuando `<tagname>` es **el nombre de un tag HTML** ambos funcionan **igual**.

Comment: Me disculpo por mi aberración y "lapsus brutus". **`$('<tagName>')` obtiene los mismos resultados que `getElementsByTagName('<tagName>')`**. Mientras que para `getElementsByTagName('<tagName>')[0]` se obtiene con jquery: `$('<tagName>:first')`.  Para la pregunta, lo más que he ahondado; la versión de jQ que usan las extensiones es v1.11.1 y compruebo que éste ejecuta bien. Ahora vamos a suponer que sea con respecto a las prioridades de ejecución que tiene el navegador frente a las demás extensiones o por la versión del navegador. **CONCLUSIÓN:** _No te confíes con el uso de las extensiones._

Comment: Mi punto es: no estás respondiendo la pregunta del OP. La pregunta es: *foo y bar deberían hacer lo mismo, pero para este sitio no funcionan igual, ¿qué sucede?*. Por favor revisa nuevamente la pregunta y algunas respuestas que hay acá, eso te ayudará en la edición de tu respuesta.

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta no responde la pregunta.